# Is this the right way to measure round-trip time?

Tags: python, performance, web, cdn, python-requests

I need to compare a few CDN services, so I write a short python script to repeatedly send get requests to resources deployed on these CDN, and record the round-trip time. I run the scripts on several PCs in different cities.
This is how I did it:

```
t0 = time.clock()
r = requests.get(test_cdn_url)
t1 = time.clock()
roundtrip = t1-t0 # in seconds
```

For most requests, the roundtrip time is within 1 second:200-500ms, but occasionally, it reports a request that finishes in several seconds: 3-5 seconds, once 9 seconds.

Is this just the way it is, or am I using the wrong tool to measure? In other words, does requests lib do something (caching or some heavy-weight operations) that makes the metric totally wrong?

Comment: Won't add an answer because I'm not sure if your metrics is wrong, but I would use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: The semicolons in your Python code are not needed and serve to make the code less readable.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You are right, old habits die hard :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Response` object provides an [`elapsed`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=elapsed#requests.Response.elapsed) attribute:

> The amount of time elapsed between sending the request and the arrival
>   of the response (as a timedelta)

Your code would then look like:

```
r = requests.get(test_cdn_url)
roundtrip = r.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that `requests` is doing anything heavy-weight (or caching), you could always use `urllib`:

```
nf = urllib.urlopen(url)
t0 = time.time()
page = nf.read()
t1 = time.time()
nf.close()

roundtrip = t1 - t0
```

Alternatively, if you include a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header along with your request, then that should ensure that no caching happens along the way - and your original code should time the request effectively.